Why does the term $ \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} $ appear in the shear stress relation $ \tau_{zx} $, and what is its effect?
In the control volume for a fluid moving with velocities $u$, $v$, and $w$ in the $x$, $y$, and $z$ directions, respectively, we observe that the bottom face of the control volume is subjected to three types of stresses,a normal stress and two shear stresses, as shown in the following figure:

I will focus here on the shear stress, which is expressed by the following relation:
$$\tau_{zx} = \mu \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} \right)$$
Before encountering this relation, I expected it to be as follows:
$$\tau_{zx} = \mu \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} \right)$$
This is because I believe that the shear stress acting on the bottom face of the control volume arises due to the effect of friction between the parallel layers. Therefore, the velocity difference $u$ in the $z$-direction seemed acceptable to me as a cause of this friction. However, what raises my question is the presence of the derivative $ \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} $ in the relation, as I cannot visualize the effect of the velocity difference in the layers perpendicular to this face on the shear stress.
Can someone explain the reason for including this term $ \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} $ in the relation and its effect on the shear stress? I would like to get an explanation that helps me adjust my perspective and understand this point better.

(Asked previously, but the asker did not find a satisfactory explanation.)
One way to look at it: A difference in the velocity $w$ in the $x$ direction would produce the same shear stress state as a difference in the velocity $u$ in the $z$ direction, the essence of shear being a change in the side angles and shape of an infinitesimal element.


(Animations show a 1-direction load acting on the 2-direction face and a 2-direction load acting on the 1-direction face, with infinitesimal deformations shown as finite for visual clarity; replace 1 and 2 with your $x$ and $z$ axes, respectively. You can ignore the $x$ and $u$ lines; these are intended for a discussion of strains in terms of vector lengths and tip movements.)
See also this discussion for another way to look at it: Conservation laws require both $\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}$ to be equally and symmetrically incorporated.
Edit: There was a question about whether the top and right forces, say, can each be labeled $F$ and combined to give a resultant of $\sqrt{2}F$, pointing to the top-right. The forces are intrinsically linked to the faces through the stress tensor; to properly reorient the element by 45°, we would transform the tensor by premultiplying and postmultiplying a rotation matrix:
$$\boldsymbol{\sigma^\prime}=a\boldsymbol{\sigma}a.$$
where $$a=\left[\begin{array}& 1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} \\ 1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2}\end{array}\right].$$
(An alternative graphical approach is Mohr's circle.) The reoriented element is subjected to equal compressive and tensile loads on the rotated faces, where the magnitudes of $\sigma_{12}=\tau_{12}$, $\sigma_{1^\prime 1^\prime}$, and $\sigma_{2^\prime 2^\prime}$ are all equal:

This is also a way of indicating a pure shear state, as is any other transformation using a different angle than 45°.
So the answer is no, we can't resolve the forces independently; we have to apply the correct tensor transformation rules.

I kindly ask you to follow along with me in what follows, even if it is based on my incorrect assumptions, so that you can point them out to me, please.
I want to move slightly away from using velocity changes and instead focus on a control volume removed from the fluid, applying a force to it. Let us assume this control volume has a side length of $a$, and I apply a shear force $F$ to its bottom surface.
According to the law of shear stress, the shear stress on the bottom face is:
$\frac{F}{a^2}$ ......

....Similarly, the shear stress on the left face of this cube is equal to the same value, according to what I understood from your previous response.
If, for example, we follow the same approach used to derive the Navier-Stokes equation, by considering shear stresses as the basis for calculating surface forces that contribute to the acceleration of the control volume according to Newton's second law, we proceed in the same manner.
We calculate the force on the bottom surface:
$\left( \frac{F}{a^2} \right) a^2 = F$
.........

.......The same applies to the left face; when we multiply its shear stress by the area, the result is also $F$.
Since the two surfaces are perpendicular, the forces acting on them are perpendicular as well. Therefore, their resultant is:$\sqrt{2} F$
We started with a force $F$ and ended up with a resultant force of $\sqrt{2} F$,Isn't this a kind of contradiction?.

The face area you’re now considering seems to have an area of $\sqrt{2}a^2$, so the factor of $\sqrt{2}$ seems to cancel out when considering stresses applied by a load on a surface.

However, when applying the second law to the control volume to derive the Navier-Stokes equation, the force on each surface of the cube was calculated by multiplying its shear stress by its area, without considering that the shear area might have changed to $\sqrt{2} \times a^2$.

Please see my edited answer.
